# Get programmatically Input Schema of model from MlFlow model registry

Tags: databricks, mlflow

Is there a way to fetch the input schema(features on which training was done) from MlFlow model registry ? The input schema is captured using 'signature' parameter when logging the trained model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will describe **two ways of doing this**.

Model signature **can be retrieved from the associated run metadata**. Here is a picture showing how to do that in UI:

[image]

Now, to extract this programmatically, note that **[logged model metadata is tracked under the `mlflow.log-model.history` tag](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html)**. Once we know the corresponding run id (we keep it at hand or query the model store) we can use this code snippet :

```py
import json
import mlflow
from mlflow.client import MlflowClient

client = MlflowClient('http://0.0.0.0:5000')
run_id = '467677aff0074955a4e75492085d52f9'
run = client.get_run(run_id)
log_model_meta = json.loads(run.data.tags['mlflow.log-model.history'])
log_model_meta[0]['signature']
```

which agrees with the figure :-)

```
{'inputs': '[{"type": "tensor", "tensor-spec": {"dtype": "float64", "shape": [-1, 4]}}]',
 'outputs': '[{"type": "tensor", "tensor-spec": {"dtype": "int64", "shape": [-1]}}]'}
```

Another way is to **query to the model store**. The schema / signature appears under the model view, like below

[image]

the data can be obtained by the function [`mlflow.models.get_model_info`](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.models.html#mlflow.models.get_model_info), like in this snippet

```py
model_uri = client.get_model_version_download_uri('toy-model','10')
model_info = mlflow.models.get_model_info(model_uri)
model_info._signature_dict
```

Comment: Thanks, can now get the features from schema registered :)

Answer (score 0):

I found mlflow.types.schema.Schema helpful as well! Considering I wanted to specifically access the column names.

```
import mlflow
from mlflow.types.schema import Schema

model_uri = f"runs:/{model_run_id}/{run_name}"

# Load model as a PyFuncModel.
model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_uri)

# Access the schema from model metadata
schema = model.metadata.signature
feature_names = Schema.input_names(schema.inputs)
target_name = Schema.input_names(schema.outputs)

print(feature_names, target_name)
```